# How do you edit a Joomla 1.5 website header tag

Tags: seo, joomla1.5

Is there any extension available to edit my website header tag? Website is created in Joomla.
I want to edit my page's header tag for SEO purpose. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting up headers in your template file.

Comment: as per ur advise in this we can edit our template  not actual website header.pls if u know give me step by step help.

Comment: You can go to template folder >> there are different templates inside it. Find the applied template. Inside it there should be index.php file. In that file you can add the headers.

Comment: is there only we can edit index page of website or another page of website.and as per suggestion where i have to go in this html or css.pls

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to edit the header, you need to where the various parts of the header are generated.

1. Title Tag - this is generated by the Title in the menu item or by the title article/K2 item is it does not have a menu item
2. Description, keywords, robots, author - these are all set within the Article or K2 item.

You can also use plugins to modify how the tags are generated - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/14567